# How to create a scheduled email job on disk space in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

How to create a job(or script or ?):

To Check disk space; when disk space left with 1.5 GB only then send alert email to some end users.

Windows Edition: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Type of Server: SQL Server Database.

I do not have experience to work with Windows or windows based technologies. Did some search and found Task scheduler but could not able to figure how to apply expected conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in `Windows Server` using `Task Scheduler` and the `System Log`. If the free space falls below the percentage specified in **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\DiskSpaceThreshold**, an event is recorded in the `System Log` that can trigger a task to send an e-mail message.You can follow the below steps -

- Open Task Scheduler and create a new task.
- Enter a name for the task,select "Run whether user is logged on or not", and check "Do not store password."
- Add a new trigger on the Triggers tab.
- Select "On an    event" in the "Begin the task" box.
- Set Log to "System", Source to    "srv", and Event ID to "2013".
- Add a new action on the Actions tab.
- Set Action to "Send an e-mail" and fill in the rest of the settings
  appropriately.
- To configure when the low disk space event is recorded in the
  System Log, open the Registry Editor, navigate to    **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters** and add a **DWORD** value named `DiskSpaceThreshold`, setting it to the desired percentage. When the entry does not exist, the default value is 10.

If you want to do this via `SQL Server` then you can write a script and then schedule the script via job which will run periodically and send alert/mail (using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`) when the disk space crosses the threshold value.

Sample query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT DB_NAME(dovs.database_id) DBName,
mf.physical_name PhysicalFileLocation,
dovs.logical_volume_name AS LogicalName,
dovs.volume_mount_point AS Drive,
CONVERT(INT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0) AS FreeSpaceInMB
FROM sys.master_files mf
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) dovs
ORDER BY FreeSpaceInMB ASC
```

check for the column `FreeSpaceInMB`

Another query -

```
EXEC master..xp_fixeddrives
```

check for the column `MBfree`

**Edit:**
Link with details on how to accomplish this through `Sql Server` - 
[link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/space/133462/)

Comment: Thanks for showing initial way. I have done steps as suggested. Nothing happens. Set Threshold value to 80 to run it properly . My C Drive 95GB free of 227 GB. D is 155GB free of 227 GB. I changed it to display message then too it is not displaying any. In Event viewer unable to find 2013. I am not regular user of windows but Linux. So please elaborate where i am doing wrong.

Comment: For the Event you need not find the ID, just type in the number (2013). It's a Microsoft defined event id `Error 2013 - Disk Is At Or Near Capacity`.

Comment: I guess your issue is not solved, I have edited my question and provided a link which would do the task for you through `Sql Server`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution and was banging my head in a wall.  After a ton of searching I convinced myself that I could do this myself.  This requires 3 scripts, 1 bat file and 2 vbs scripts (because I actually send out warnings before alerts).  The warnings are sent to email and can be ignored afterhours but the alerts are sent to phones via email to sms gateways (I'll have to work on getting a direct sms solution eventually).

Let's start.  Here's the bat file that determines how much free space is available on the disk in question:

```
@echo off
:: Copyright Lou Spinuso 2017
:: This script calculates the amount of free space on a disk and returns the percentage
:: This can be used with a task scheduler job to verify that more than 10% 
:: (or prefered threshold) of disk is available and then set to send alerts if it fails
:: You will require setting the path to where grep and awk exists as these are required
:: in order to extract the values necessary
:: alternatively you can use find and for to get the right values

:: this is needed to enable setting some variables in the IF statement
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: SCRIPT_HOME = home directory for script and VB Script
:: DISK_TEST = Disk to test
:: GNU_TOOLS = location of grep and awk
:: DTFile = log file written with total disk size
:: DFFile = log file written with free disk space

set SCRIPT_HOME=C:\Monitor\Disk
set DISK_TEST=C:
set GNU_TOOLS=c:\gnu_tools\bin
set DTFile=C:\Monitor\disktotal.log
set DFFile=C:\Monitor\diskfree.log
set WarnValue=10
set AlertValue=5
set PATH=%PATH%;%GNU_TOOLS%

::fsutil is a built-in windows application
fsutil volume diskfree %DISK_TEST%|grep -i "total # of bytes" |awk "{print $6}" >%DTFile%
fsutil volume diskfree %DISK_TEST%|grep -i "total # of free bytes" |awk "{print $7}" >%DFFile%

:: setting variables from files since batch files can't do it 
:: directly from a command that I've been able to find
set /P DiskTotal= < %DTFile%
set /P DiskFree= < %DFFile%

:: call to function that calculates the length of the variables
:: for disk size.  This is because set /a will only calcuate 
:: 32 bits or up to 2,147,483,647, or 2 GB
:: and fsutil returns number of bytes which can get up to TB's
:: Using this we can effectively chop the right most digits
:: effectively dividing by orders of magnitude later
call :strlen DiskTotalLen DiskTotal
call :strlen DiskFreeLen DiskFree

::echo DiskTotalLen= %DiskTotalLen%
::echo DiskFreeLen = %DiskFreeLen%

:: setting variables just in case we are working with small disks
set DFLLeftMost=%DiskFreeLen%
set DTLLeftMost=%DiskTotalLen%

:: if statement that checks if numbers we're looking at are 
:: 9,999,999 or smaller.  This is because we need to make the
:: disk free variable 2 oom > than the disk size variable 
:: in order to have returned a whole number
:: (no decimal values are returned)
:: also, as a result of using "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion"
:: we should use ! instead of % in the if statement

if %DiskTotalLen% GTR 7 (
    set /a Subtractor=!DiskTotalLen! - 7
    set /a DTLLeftMost=!DiskTotalLen!-!Subtractor!
    set /a DFLLeftMost=!DiskFreeLen!-!Subtractor!+2
    )

:: dividing values by oom
call set DiskFree=%%DiskFree:~0,%DFLLeftMost%%%
::  echo %DiskFree%
call set DiskTotal=%%DiskTotal:~0,%DTLLeftMost%%%
::  echo %DiskTotal%

:: set value in text file for reading
set /a DiskPercent=%DiskFree%/%DiskTotal%

if %DiskPercent% LSS %WarnValue% (
    if %DiskPercent% LSS %AlertValue% (cscript.exe %SCRIPT_HOME%\Alert.vbs "!COMPUTERNAME!" "!DiskPercent!"
      ) ELSE (cscript.exe %SCRIPT_HOME%\Warn.vbs "!COMPUTERNAME!" "!DiskPercent!")
)
::echo %DiskPercent% > c:\monitor\diskpercent.log
::echo %DiskPercent%

goto :eof

:: function to count the length of a variable.  Not sure what this all
:: means, this was written by 'jeb' on stackoverflow
:: ht tp://stack overflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
      if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
         set /a "len+=%%P"
         set "s=!s:~%%P!"
      )
    )
)
(
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

From here we now need the vbs scripts that will send the emails.  Here is the "alert" vbs script named, aptly, "alert.vbs".  A second vbs, almost identical to this one named, "warn.vbs" is also required.  You will have to make sure you correctly set the values for

- objEmail.From
- objEmail.To
- objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item *the one that specifies smtp server*

also the port for your mail server if it's not 25.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    WScript.Echo "Missing Parameters"
end if

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "Monitor@yourcompany.com"
objEmail.To = "supportguyspager@yourcompany.com"
objEmail.Subject = "ALERT!!!!  Server "+WScript.Arguments(0)+" is low on disk space"
objEmail.Textbody = "Critical disk space issue.  Please clear some space on C drive on server . " + WScript.Arguments(0)
objEmail.Textbody = objEmail.Textbody + vbCrLf + "Server is at " + WScript.Arguments(1) +" percent free Disk Space"

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("ht tp://schemas.micro soft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("ht tp://schemas.micro soft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="mail.yourcompany.com"
'Server port
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("ht tp://schemas.micro soft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

objEmail.Send

set objEmail=nothing
```

I then set these to run on the server in task scheduler every 15 minutes and when the disk free space is below the threshold (in percentage), a warning or an alert is sent out.

Hopefully I answered this question well enough for enough other people that are looking for a similar solution.

Final note, I had to break up the "urls" in the code because I don't have enough reputation to post them.  You should be able to just remove the whitespace and party on.